# Appending and Prepending values by checking a field in JSON string

Tags: perl

Below is the json string that has to be parsed

```
 [{"mnemonic":"SIG1039.CA.01","ID":"203024","portList":null},{"mnemonic":"SIG0315.OR.01","ID":"035066","portList":03}
```

In the above json format 
if the portlist is empty then

1. Create 2 values by appending 03 and 04  and prepend 7802 to ID .

   > i.e 780220302403,780220302404
2. OR if the portlist has an entry just append it and prepend 7802 to ID

   > i.e 780203506603

Is the code below correct, I used map to acheive it,but not proper
What would be the correct approach.

```
use lib '.';
use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);
use File::Find;
use Switch;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
open my $my_fh, '<', 'Data.txt' or die $!;
my $data = <$fh_ptoto_wiu>;
my $decoded_data = decode_json $data;
for (@$decoded_data ){
  my ($value) =  map { $_ eq null ? [7802.$_->{ID}.03,7802.$_->{ID}.04] : 7802.$_->{ID}.$_->{portList} } $_->{portList};
  push @myarray,$value;
 }
```

Comment: What do you want us to tell you? You already said it's _nt proper_. What does that mean?

Comment: Your code won't compile. There is no `null` in Perl (unless you defined a function called `null` and didn't show it to us).

Comment: @simbabque What would be the correct approach, Where has it gone wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: You have not included what the output is now. Or what modules you are using. And your code doesn't compile. What's `$id`? Did you mean `"null"`? In addition to that, your input data is invalid. It complains about _malformed number (leading zero must not be followed by another digit), at character offset 114 (before "3}\n")_ for me, and the closing `]` is missing.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating your life here. Don't try to build a complicated `map` just because you think it's cool. You have pretty clear rules written out there. Just build them in as many lines as you need. You can optimize later.

Comment: `my $data = <$fh_ptoto_wiu>;` should be `my $data = do { local $/; <$fh_ptoto_wiu> };`. `$_ eq null` should be `!defined($_)`. `push @myarray,$id;` should be `push @myarray,$value;`

Comment: I have a solution written out, and I'm going to share it. But I strongly suggest you pay more attention to detail in the future. Using the wrong variable names and leaving out obvious parts of the program in questions here is just wasting the time of nice people that try to help you. At least help them help you in the future.

Comment: @simbabque : Changed the code , there is ID in the data,and changed it in the code

Comment: You could at least give us valid JSON to work with!

Comment: @LearningCpp: By posting a question here, you are asking for the attention of many people around the world. If you want our help, you need to make it as easy as possible for us to help you. You need to post code that compiles. And your sample data needs to be correct. Neither of those things were true here. If you don't do that, people will quickly get bored and not bother to work on your question. If you consistently post questions like that, then people will start to ignore your questions or you will be downvoted so you can no longer post questions.

Comment: Sure, will keep that in mind , Thanks

Comment: @LearningCpp After a lot of edits , you got it right finally :),Get it almost right in the first go, there are people who can help u here only if they can understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, I needed to fix the JSON. The `03` in the second `portList` needs to be quoted because of the leading zero, and the closing `]` for the array was missing.

The following program demonstrates how to solve your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON 'decode_json';
use Data::Printer;    

my $data         = <DATA>;
my $decoded_data = decode_json $data;

my @myarray;
foreach my $obj (@$decoded_data) {
    my $value;
    if ( $obj->{portList} ) {
        # if the portlist has an entry just append it and prepend 7802 to ID
        $value = [ '7802' . $obj->{ID} . $obj->{portList} ];
    } else {
        # Create 2 values by appending 03 and 04 and prepend 7802 to ID
        $value = [
            '7802' . $obj->{ID} . '03',
            '7802' . $obj->{ID} . '04',
        ];
    }

    push @myarray, $value;
}

p @myarray;

__DATA__
[{"mnemonic":"SIG1039.CA.01","ID":"203024","portList":null},{"mnemonic":"SIG0315.OR.01","ID":"035066","portList":"03"}]
```

The output looks pretty much like your examples.

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] 780220302403,
        [1] 780220302404
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] 780203506603
    ]
]
```

You need to know that a `null` value will convert to `undef` when you use the JSON module in Perl. You were doing a string equal `eq` with the literal `null`, which just doesn't exist in your program. Just using `null` will make Perl think it's an unquoted string because there is no function of that name, which is not allowed (because of `strict`). If you'd quote it, it would still not make sense. It would give a "Use of uninitialized value" warning.

Besides that, don't do `map` if you can do a loop to make stuff more clear.

Comment: This if condition  is working to value with null  if( $_->{portList} eq "")

Comment: The "null" in JSON gets converted to `undef` in a Perl data structure. So I think that `if (defined $_->{portList})` is the best check to. Comparing with an empty string will probably work too - but you will get a warning under `use warnings`.

Comment: Can we send json data as an argument to a function. Like
my $json_data  =  decode_json $my_file_data;
fetch_json_data($json_data);
sub fetch_json_data
{    my $data = @_; } does not work, do we need to use specific json functions for achieving this

Comment: You need parentheses around the variable if you use `@_` because in scalar context you'll get the number of elements. I think you should read a book about Perl basics at some point. ;-)

Comment: If you dare to come to England then I will assault you as you disembark and pummel you until you denounce your preference for `Data::Printer`. I will also buy you a pint or two when we're both exhausted. :)

Comment: @borodin LPW it is then. :-D

Comment: `my $data = @_` is never going to work. Are you trying to learn Perl by guesswork?

Comment: @DaveCross: That's unhelpful without explaining *why* it doesn't work. And I'm unclear about who your comment was meant for, but without an assignment you are talking to the author **simbabque**. I can't see any mention of `my $data = @_` anywhere on this page, but I assure you that simbabque knows Perl pretty damn well.

Comment: @Borodin: Sorry, it was a response to @LearningCpp's comment starting "Can we send json_data..." in which he uses `my $data = @_` to attempt to get some data that was passed into a subroutine. It's @LearningCpp who is learning Perl by guesswork; I'm well aware of @simbabque's level of expertise :-)

Comment: @Dave, Borodin, we should all grab a pint I think. :)